# Java based client for Project reactor in pre Sping boot 2?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

So far I have seen examples for clients to use spring-webflux in spring boot 2 which has WebClient and WebTestClient. I've got consumers who still use Spring boot 1.5 and wants to use reactive services written in Spring boot 1.5 on the server. We can't upgrade our services to spring boot 2 due to third-party libraries we use. Looking for client examples which consume Flux APIs? Can anyone share the examples?

Comment: Wrote a small client based on Spring Boot 2 and receiving an object with null values on the client side. Any reason why fields have null values? I know the server is populating the Flux with one entity object but it is not showing up on the client side. This is the client side code <br/>  `Flux<Entity> entityFlux = client.get().uri("/events/skus")
                    .header("accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).retrieve().bodyToFlux(Entity.class);
            entityFlux.subscribe(System.out::println);`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but if it is about a different app coded in Spring Boot 1.5/WebMVC that calls a newer app coded in Spring Boot 2/WebFlux, then it is still HTTP1.1 between the two, so having 1 reactive side changes nothing.

Comment: I upgraded server side to Spring boot 2.1.0 and I was able to test my Flux<Entity> endpoint in postman and it works. So trying to write client using WebClient and it doesn't seem to be working. Here is the code snippet and just want to invoke the toString method on the entity object on the client and wanna share this piece of code with our consumers of this API.

Comment: I upgraded server side to Spring boot 2.1.0 and I was able to test my Flux<Entity> endpoint in postman and it works. So trying to write a client using WebClient and it doesn't seem to be printing the contents.`.
            Flux<ProductAssortmentEntity> entityBody = client.post().uri(URL + "/skus").body(BodyInserters.fromObject([1001731456]")).header("ContentType","application/json").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)     .retrieve().bodyToFlux(ProductAssortmentEntity.class).subscribe(System.out::println);
            },
....    
`